# Convert chart form excel to powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

```
    Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject
 
    On Error Resume Next
    Set newPowerPoint = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
 
    If newPowerPoint Is Nothing Then
        Set newPowerPoint = New PowerPoint.Application
    End If

    If newPowerPoint.Presentations.Count = 0 Then
        newPowerPoint.Presentations.Add
    End If
 
    newPowerPoint.Visible = True

    For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
            
        cht.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
        activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select

        activeSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 15
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 125
    
        activeSlide.Shapes(2).Width = 200
        activeSlide.Shapes(2).Left = 505
        
        If InStr(activeSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "US") Then
            activeSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Range("J7").Value & vbNewLine
            activeSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter (Range("J8").Value & vbNewLine)
        ElseIf InStr(activeSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "Renewable") Then
            activeSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Range("J27").Value & vbNewLine
            activeSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter (Range("J28").Value & vbNewLine)
            activeSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter (Range("J29").Value & vbNewLine)
        End If

        activeSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 16

    Next
 
AppActivate ("PowerPoint")
Set activeSlide = Nothing
Set newPowerPoint = Nothing
```

> it my code on windown but when i run it on macos. `newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add`  has stuck on 2-3 minutes in here, sometime `activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial` Compile error: Method or data member not found. on excel on macos haven't PasteSpecical, so I change it to `myslide.Shapes.Paste.Select` but it wrong and stuck overtime somebody can help me how to convert excel to powerpoint from excel pls. thanks to read...!

Comment: Your code uses OLE, which is extremely slow and rather buggy in Office for Mac. I'm not clear why your post title mentions AppleScript when you're using VBA.

Comment: yes, I used vba

Comment: can u help me to convert excel to powerpoint with vba. when i used this code in window it run but mac not :(

Comment: The PowerPoint for Mac object model is not as complete as the one for the Windows version. Sometimes you can work around a problem with alternate VBA code, sometimes, you can use AppleScript to work around the problem. These workarounds can take many hours of experimentation to find. Best of luck.